# Get dynamic value to plugin options after the dom load. (Fineuploader plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins, plugins

I am hoping for your help on this one.

I am using Fineuploader and I need to get and send input field value (that will be file group title).

For that I am using path to server side script (I didn't code it thats why I have to do it on my side, somehow):

```
endpoint: '/Services/hndFileUploader.ashx?case=deals&dealfiletitle=' + $("input").val()
```

Problem is that DOM with Fineuploader is already loaded and value of input is of course empty.

How can I get dynamic value to send with that query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this using the `setParams` option for fineuploader. [Docs are here](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/blob/master/readme.md), but basically it could be something like:

```
$('#fineUploaderElementId').fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: '/Services/hndFileUploader.ashx'
    }
}).on('submit', function(event, id, filename) {
     $(this).fineUploader('setParams', {'case': 'deals', 'dealfiletitle': $(input).val(); });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @mccannf, I will try now, but I think it will be exactly what I need. Didn't even try setParams, because was confused with endpoint path query.